# PHP Function with API How Many Requests?

Tags: php, function, api, loops, request

I have the following *`function`* which requests data from an API URL. I was wondering that if I call the function 5 times with different parameters this equals to 5 Requests to API ?.

If that is true I want to avoid "Too Many Requests". I was thinking to put outside the function the `file_get_contents()`, `json_decode()` and the `$url` so I can request data from the URL once but I have to declare my variables as `globals` inside the *`function`* which is a bad approach as I found.

```
function apiReq($type, $day){

    $url2 = "http://api.example.com/../.../../";

    $str2 = file_get_contents($url2);

    $decode_two = json_decode($str2, TRUE);

    foreach($decode_two['teams'][$type][$day] as $item ) {
        if (isset($item['name']['initial'])) {
            echo $item['name']['initial'];
        }
        echo $item['name']['surname'];
        echo $item['shirt'];
        echo '</br>';
    }
}

apiReq('A', 'Monday');

apiReq('B', 'Tuesday');

echo '</br>';

apiReq('C', 'Monday');

apiReq('D', 'Tuesday');

apiReq('F', 'Friday');
```

What would be the best approach to avoid "Too Many Requests"?

Thank you

Comment: Does the data from the api change for each different request? If yes how many possible combinations of data are possible with the different parameters of `$type` and `$day`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data changes five times a week, there are many possible combinations available. There are Types from A,B,C to K and Days from Monday to Saturday. All are possible combinations with each other.

Comment: would there be any issues regarding privacy if a different user were to access a stored copy of the data or is it innocuous in nature? You could theoretically save a daily copy of the data for each $type

Comment: @RamRaider I don't think there will be any issues regarding privacy as data are not confidential. What bothers me are the requests, I want to avoid to make to many requests because there are many combinations. A second thought was to store first the data on another database and then pull the data from there.

Comment: if there are A-K possible `$types` per day and 5 possible days does that then equate to a max of 55 possible combinations per week?

Comment: @RamRaider Correct!

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array storing something like `[ ["type" => $type, "day" => $day] ]` instead of calling the function 5 times, since you request the same URL each time, so you can loop over that array

In example :

```
// Get an array as parameter
//                    |
//                    V
function apiReq($TypesAndDays){

    $url2 = "http://api.example.com/../.../../";

    $str2 = file_get_contents($url2);

    $decode_two = json_decode($str2, TRUE);

    // Loop over that array
    foreach ($TypesAndDays as $TypeAndDay)
    {
        // set $type and $day
        $type = $TypeAndDay['type'];
        $day = $TypeAndDay['day'];

        // the rest of your code remains unchanged
        foreach($decode_two['teams'][$type][$day] as $item ) {
            if (isset($item['name']['initial'])) {
                echo $item['name']['initial'];
            }
            echo $item['name']['surname'];
            echo $item['shirt'];
            echo '</br>';
        }
    }
}

$TypesAndDays = [
    [ 'type' => 'A', 'day' => 'Monday' ],
    [ 'type' => 'B', 'day' => 'Tuesday' ],
    [ 'type' => 'C', 'day' => 'Monday' ],
    [ 'type' => 'D', 'day' => 'Tuesday' ],
    [ 'type' => 'F', 'day' => 'Friday' ]
];

apiReq($TypesAndDays);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interesting approach, I was wondering though each time the function `apiReq()` access the array `$TypesAndDays` that means another Request to the `$url2`?

Comment: No, the access is done there `file_get_contents($url2);` and only there. The response is then fetch from the api and treated as is, without any furthers calls or requests